# How to exclude the empty list from JSON during the Serialization using the Jackson Serializer?

Tags: java, json, jackson, jackson-databind, jackson2

How to avoid writing the empty list using the Jackson Custom serializer? Currently, it's adding the empty list: `"list" : [ ]` but I want it to completely skip it, either with some annotations or using the custom sealizer. I have created the demo with `Collections.emptyList()`, I am aware that if I remove then it will skip the empty list but this is just for demo purposes and I want to skip using some other approach:

MyClass:

```
@Data
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY)
@AllArgsConstructor
public class MyClass {
    private String type;

    private String name;

    @JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY)
    @JsonSerialize(using = CustomSearilizer.class)
    private List<Object> list;
}
```

CustomSearilizer:

```
public class CustomSearilizer extends JsonSerializer<List<Object>> {
    @Override
    public void serialize(final List<Object> context, final JsonGenerator jsonGenerator, final SerializerProvider serializers) throws IOException {

        jsonGenerator.writeStartArray();

        context.stream().forEach(item -> {
            if (item instanceof Map) {
                Map<String, String> entries = (Map<String, String>) item;
                entries.entrySet().stream().forEach(entry -> {
                    try {
                        jsonGenerator.writeStartObject();
                        jsonGenerator.writeStringField(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
                        jsonGenerator.writeEndObject();
                    } catch (IOException ex) {
                        throw new RuntimeException(ex);
                    }

                });
            }
        });

        jsonGenerator.writeEndArray();
    }
}
```

Main:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonProcessingException {
        final ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        objectMapper.setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY);

        final MyClass myClass = new MyClass("My Name", "My Type", Collections.emptyList());

        System.out.println(objectMapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(myClass));
    }
}
```

This is providing me with following JSON:

```
{
  "type" : "My Name",
  "name" : "My Type",
  "list" : [ ]
}
```

I would like to create it following JSON:

```
{
  "type" : "My Name",
  "name" : "My Type"
}
```

This is just a demo so I have added collections.emptyList to re-create the issue but is there any way I can skip adding these emptyList in JSON when using the customsealizer?

Comment: If you use a custom serializer you need do an override of the isEmpty method to make it work. And I know about other solution but I never testing since I prefer do my own implementation but if you add the following params into the annotation should work too  ```@JsonSerialize(using=YourCustomSerializer.class, include=JsonInclude.NON_NULL)```

Comment: @AdrianLagartera Thanks a lot for providing the answer but I did not follow completely because if I am adding based on your approach then I am getting the error: `Cannot resolve symbol `NON_NULL``. Following is something that I have added: ` @JsonSerialize(using = CustomSearilizer.class, include=JsonInclude.NON_NULL)`. Can you please provide some more explanation?

Comment: You tried the first one? When you implements the custom serializer you can override the `isEmpty` method, if you do that, you need check the empty values you want check in your case just the list. The second one I put was a option I never tried myself so, I can't provide you more information, but should work.

Comment: @AdrianLagartera I tried the first one where I checked for the `isEmpty` for the `list` in `CustomSearilizer `. If it is empty then I am skipping it, if I do that then it adds the `list` key to my JSON and skips the values, this is a bit odd and not the standard JSON I expect. I want it to completely skip the `list` element from JSON if it does not contain any values. With regards to second option I could not find any article or proper documentation, can you at least provide some link which i can refer?

Comment: The only post I remember is this (https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/misc/jackson/json-include-customized.html) but I dont know what version Jackson is using, remember Jackson have a few changes after 2.1+. Btw they use filters for each custom field, so it should work with that use of filters.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran a test and just adding the annotation `@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY)` to the serialized class did the trick. No other action was needed. No custom serializer and no modification for ObjectMapper configuration. Here is the article that eaplains the example:
[Jackson JSON - @JsonInclude NON_EMPTY Example](https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/misc/jackson/json-include-non-empty.html)

Comment: @Micheal I need to include the `CustomSearilizer` for my `List<Object> list` because it's `List<Object>` and if it has the values then I need to Serialize in my own format so I need to have this. However, if the List is empty then I need to completely skip it. So I believe just adding `@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY)` is not working for me when using with `CustomSearilizer`

Comment: Well, I guess custom serializer ignores the annotation, so you have to take care of it in your custom serializer.

Comment: ok, do you have any idea how to do it? If i add `.isEmpty` then it adds the key `list` but skips the value which is odd. Do you have any other suggestion.

Comment: No, I don't, I usually try to avoid custom serializer if I can solve my issue in any other way